# How to read a group of characters in C?

Tags: c, char

My question is really basic, I was wondering how can I scanf a group of characters, like a word, attribute the word to a variable and then print it

As far as I know, I have to define my variables, like

```
char word;
```

Then like

```
scanf("%c", &word);
```

But when I do `printf("\n %c", word)`; it gives me a strange character, not the whole group of characters `w + o + r + d`

I guess i'm missing something like declare an array idk, xD
can someone teach me?

Comment: What you mean with: *strange character*, can you be more specific?

Comment: like a special character, a sun, a moon, a random stuff, but I got it, I can not use %c, I have to use %s because it is a string, right?

Comment: Yes and please, read what a string in c is. It's really important to fully understand that, if you get to understand it then you will know where the `"%15s"` comes from. Also read [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

Comment: The code you actually posted would print `w`  . Your real code must be different if you're getting strange characters.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense... You should post more complete example, and also tell  what is your input. If current code prints single garbage char, it is because scanf failed, and ’word’ remains uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

If you just use the `%s` string formatter like so with a character array:

```
char word[16];
if (scanf("%15s", word) != 1) /* The correct way to use `scanf()' */
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: this is really wierd but possible!\n");
else
    fprintf(stdout, "Ok, so the input is: %s\n", word);
```

Comment: This is wrong, what is the type of `&word`? I always see how `scanf()` is misused, it's a really ugly function.

Comment: Either use `word` or `&word[0]`, `&word` is totally wrong.

Comment: @iharob and MarcoBonelli: Sorry, I haven't used C in a while. Let me fix that. My mistake =P. I've totally forgotten about pointers and arrays after coding with JS and HTML for so long now...

Answer (score 0):

To get a string of characters as input from the user you should use `fgets()`. The reason being is you can specify how many characters the user is allowed to input to prevent buffer overflows.

```
char word[5];
fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin);
```

Here is the related [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) for the function: